# I am trying to remove Ubuntu and reinstall Windows 10, can someone help me?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

So I'm in love with Ubuntu. It's fast, clean, and efficient. However there are certain things that I can't do that I used to love to do on my Windows 10. I tried creating a bootable USB using UnetBootin, however it failed to actually do anything, and killed my USB drive (Not that I'm mad, I got it specifically with the intention of reinstalling windows, so it was cheap). Now I need to reinstall Windows and I'm in dire need of assistance.

When I tried booting from my USB (before it died on me) it took me straight to the UnetBootin boot page (granted I had to hit F2). However there was no option to boot from USB, and the one thing that happened when I hit enter was that it would start the 'automatic boot' count down again. I let the count down run, and it just simply restarted again. I remember being smart enough when I was younger to dual boot (Back when I had Vista) but this time I just didn't (maybe because I thought I wouldn't want to go back?)

Anyway, I really really *really* need help.

Comment: You can dual-boot Linux/Ubuntu and Windows if you want to use both.

Answer (score 0):

You might retitle the question, since as it is, it has almost nothing to do with Ubuntu.  The part that is Ubuntu related is how do you create a bootable media from the downloaded Windows 10 ISO.  First, hashcheck the downloaded ISO.  I found that ISO was not recognized as an ISO by much on the Ubuntu side, and even on a Windows 8 machine, the ISO fs was something like UDF and not handled by the usual Windows burn mechanism.  I did succeed on Windows 8 by using Rufus to create a CD-ROM.  You might try asking for a Rufus like program which will correctly handle the Win 10 ISO.